# XML-RPC aplication blocked by the hosting

Tags: xml-rpc

Currently I own several developments in **C# in .Net**.

These applications frequently updates information in **WordPress** using **XML-RPC**. The aim of these developments is to update information in an Extranet from local systems.

Sometimes the hosting blocks our IP because it believes that we are a robot that is doing something malicious. But that's not the reason, simply we are updating some data.

My question is for those who have worked with such updates via XML-RPC. Do you have any recommendation to avoid these blocks? Thank you!

Comment: tell the hosts mark said they are idiots ;) yeh, there is no other way to describe this kind of mutilation of core worpress functionality at the hosting level :(

Comment: In the hosting even they realize that it is an XML-RPC. He says that we are sending many emails. So I try to find a way to sidetrack their automatic locking rules. Maybe by limiting connections or frequency. But I wanted to ask you if there is any good practice recommended.

Comment: obviously you should not flood requests to keep the server from overloading, but if you wait for a response before sending the next one, you should be ok in my book

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am trying to put a limit to not flood, fore instance no more than 30 updates.